# What is the difference between json.JSONDecoder().decode() and json.loads()

Tags: python, json

I am using `urllib2` to grab the html of a url and then a regex to extract a JSON that I need from there. I want to get the usual "dictionary of dictionaries" Python object and both of the following work:

```
my_json #a correctly formatted json string
json_dict1 = json.JSONDecoder().decode(my_json)
json_dict2 = json.loads(my_json)
```

What is the difference and which is better in what circumstances (besides mine, but that one in particular)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`json.loads()` essentially creates a `json.JSONDecoder()` instance and calls `decode` on it. As such your first line is **exactly the same thing** as the second line. See the [`json.loads()` source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/887526ebb013/Lib/json/__init__.py#l293).

The module offers you flexibility; a simple function API or a full OO API that you can subclass if needed.